# How to store a user id using service worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

Is there a way to store a user id and potentially other information with service worker?

So that when you send a push notification to it, it is able to use that locally stored information and do something with it?

I tried to use localStorage, but it doesn't seem to recognise it.

As I got this error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Local storage is not available in Service Workers [because it does not have an asynchronous API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API#Service_worker_concepts_and_usage). Service workers are designed to be fully async, so no synchronous APIs are available in a Service Worker context. You can use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) instead, although unfortunately it has a much clumsier API.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb or another IndexedDB wrapper that uses promises will make your service worker integration a lot cleaner.

Comment: I found also this library, idb-kv-store: https://github.com/xuset/idb-kv-store. It seems much simple!

Answer (score 5):

Wanted to accomplish the same thing recently. IndexedDB just seemed so heavy for just passing the UID. But then I realized you can pass a UID through query params in the service worker url path...

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register(`/public/js/lib/service-worker.js?uid=${window.uid}`).then((reg) => {
```

...then just access it by parsing `location` inside the service worker.

Comment: so that becomes like a cookie essentially? Another way to tag users?

Answer (score 1):

PARAMS en la llamda JS del servicio y recuperar el valor en  **self.location.search** en service worker.

**index.html**

```
window.my_user_id = 16;
```

**RegisterSW()**

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('PNServiceWorker.js?my_user_id='+window.my_user_id)
```

*en el Service Worker, self.location.search contendra el valor: ?uid=16*

**Save Subscription Server:**

```
 ....
if (self.location.search !== undefined) {
    body.params = self.location.search.substring(1);  // my_user_id=16        
}        
var fetchdata = {
        method: 'post',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
}
var response = await fetch(strSubscriberURL, fetchdata);
return await response.json();
...
```